# AWS Glue/Athena: Do partitions help query performance if they are not used in query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

We have a use case as follows:

1. An IoT device uploads data to S3. Here an AWS Lambda function decodes the data and writes the result as parquet files in another S3 bucket. The structure is as follows:

```
s3://bucket/projectx/deviceid/tbl_message/tripid/xyz.parquet
```

2. We then use AWS Athena plus the Athena Grafana plugin to enable dashboard visualization of the data. This works overall great.
3. Unfortunately, new trips are not automatically added in this setup as Athena is unable to see new partitions. This has the downside that a user refreshing the dashboard can see new data within a single trip - but not new trip information.

There are a couple of ways around this:

1. AWS Glue could be setup to run a crawler e.g. every 1 hour to partially resolve this. But it becomes excessively costly for this use case.
2. The Lambda function could integrate with Athena to run an `MSCK REPAIR TABLE tbl_message` with every log file processed - but that adds a rather annoying cross dependency between Lambda and Athena that we prefer to avoid.
3. The queries in Grafana could run an the same command as in 2) - but that creates weird behavior where a user loading the dashboard initially won't see new trips - but if he then hits refresh a while after, then the trips would show up.

None of the above solutions are ideal. We have therefore considered changing the S3 path we write to as follows:

```
s3://bucket/projectx/deviceid/tbl_message/tripid_xyz.parquet
```

This has the implication that data for new trips will indeed show up automatically because we eliminate the partitioning of the data. This seems like the cleanest and simplest solution - but it will also mean that there can be several GB of data within a single `tbl_message` folder on S3.

Note that, regardless of the setup, we would not explicitly use the `tripid` partition layer in any of the Athena queries, as our users will purely query based on time - not based on trips.

Our question is therefore this:

In a scenario where our Athena queries do not leverage the `tripid` partition layer, is there any real downside (performance wise) from removing it as suggested - or will it in practice be the same?